# Extract PDF Annotation

Tags: c#, annotations, itext, extract, pdfbox

I need to Extract and Read only the annotation of PDF using C#.

I can extract the file without any problem by using both PDFBox and itextsharp but I need to read the annotation text or underlined or coloured (highlighted lines).

Any idea?

Comment: The answer for PDFBox is the same re PDF internals. Of course the code is different. To extract from an annotation area, see the  PrintURLs example from the source code download.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr do you have C# code of the PrintURLs?

Comment: No, only java. But C# and java are quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that there is a difference between the actual content of a page (the content that is described using PDF syntax in the *content stream* of a page) and the annotations that are added to a page (the content that is described in the annotation dictionaries in the `/Annots` entry of the page dictionary).

So far, you are extracting the content of the annotation dictionaries, but you also want to extract the content from the content stream of which the location is identified using the `/Rect` entry of the annotation. You need to parse the content stream of the page to do that.

Please go to the [official iText web site](http://itextpdf.com) and read the FAQ, more specifically: [How to read text from a specific position?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-read-text-specific-position)

Suppose that `reader` is your `PdfReader` instance, `rect` is the `Rectangle` defining the location of the text you want to extract, and `page` the corresponding page number, then you can create a `RenderFilter` and use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` like this:

```
RenderFilter[] filter = {new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect)};
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy =
    new FilteredTextRenderListener(
        new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
String text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy));
```

Comment: For some annotation kinds actually the **QuadPoints** are more concise than the **Rect**. And in case of markup annotations the **AP** appearance streams may still mark a differing subset of the text. But no one will want to try and determine text ranges by these appearances...

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie I just need to get the highlighted sentence in pdf file which is added by annotation